# Error message: no match for operator< as battery_sub_ is a subscriber and battery is a double

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ros

I am currently doing on a project that requires me to create a publisher and subscriber. The idea of this project is that I have to subscribe to the battery information of the driverless vehicle, and once the battery level of the vehicle is lower than the specified battery level (around 30%), the buzzer will ring and the red led will light up. I have managed to subscribe to the rostopic named agv_battery_level, and I have created a variable named battery for the specified battery level. However, the problem I faced was I was unable to pass the subscriber to the conditional statement, as the error message will pop out. I would like to know on how to create a variable for the battery_sub_ and pass it into the conditional statement. Thanks so much!

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

#define CRC16 0x8005

#define REPLY_SIZE 1
#define TIMEOUT 1000

#define btoa(x) ((x)?"true":"false")
//ROS Parameter Default
#define MAIN_FREQ          1.0          //Controller main frequency
#define MODBUS_CMD_SEND_DELAY_T 0.05      //unit:s, 0: not appcation, >0: appcation
#define MODBUS_CMD_RESEND_MAX 0         //0: not appcation, >0: appcation
#define MODBUS_CMD_RESEND_TIME 0.5      //unit:s
#define MODBUS_RECVEIE_TIMEOUT 1.0      //unit:s
#define TF_OUTPUT_ENABLE 0
#define FRAME_BUFF_MAX 256


//------------------------------------------
unsigned char data[6];

//------------------------------------------
ros::Publisher estop_pub_;

//------------------------------------------
//ROS Parameter
double main_freq_=MAIN_FREQ ;
double modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_=MODBUS_CMD_SEND_DELAY_T;
std::string modbus_port_;
std::string modbus_baud_;
std_msgs::String bmsg;
double modbus_cmd_resend_max_=MODBUS_CMD_RESEND_MAX;
double modbus_cmd_resend_time_=MODBUS_CMD_RESEND_TIME;
double modbus_recveie_timeout_=MODBUS_RECVEIE_TIMEOUT;
bool tf_output_enable_=TF_OUTPUT_ENABLE;
double battery;

//---------------------------------------------------
//for UART recveier time-out setting
fd_set rset;
int ret = 0;
struct timeval tv;

//---------------------------------------------------
int rev_frame_size=0;
int frame_sent=0;
int frame_recved=0;
int frame_checked=0;
unsigned char frame_bytes[FRAME_BUFF_MAX];
unsigned int frame_idx=0;
unsigned short frame_crc16=0;
int frame_resend_cnt=0;
int trans_step=0;
int trans_next=0;
static int get_new_cmd=0;
static short trans_vLa=0;
static short trans_vRa=0;
//------------------------------------------
double cmd_vel_v=0;
double cmd_vel_w=0;


static char fault_clear = 1;

static char temp_count = 0;


int count = 0;
int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
unsigned buffer[1000];
unsigned int buf_cnt=0;
bool frame_get_flag=0;
unsigned int frame_rev_freq_cnt=0;
unsigned char read_bytes[800];
unsigned int read_idx=0;
bool syn_flag=0;
int syn_num=0;

ros::Time current_ctime, last_ctime;
double cdt=0;
bool get_ctime=0;

//Odometry
ros::Time time1, time2, odom_current_time, odom_last_time;
ros::Time current_time;

unsigned short crc_fn(unsigned char *dpacket, unsigned int len) // CRC Function(Error calcualtion)
{
    unsigned short crc = 0xffff,poly = 0xa001; //Modbus CRC-16
    unsigned short i=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        crc^= (unsigned short) dpacket[i];
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(crc & 0x01)
            {
                crc >>= 1;
                crc ^= poly;
            }
            else
                crc >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return (crc);
}


void write_modbus(unsigned char *data, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned short crc16;
    unsigned char buff[40];
    unsigned char crc16_data[2];
    unsigned short i=0;

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
        buff[i]=data[i];
    crc16=crc_fn(&buff[0], len); //modbus CRC16
    crc16_data[0]=(unsigned char)(crc16 & 0xff);
    crc16_data[1]=(unsigned char)((crc16 >> 8) & 0xff);
    buff[len+1-1]=crc16_data[0];
    buff[len+2-1]=crc16_data[1];
    printf("crc16=%d\n", crc16);
    printf("crc16_data[0]=0x%02X, crc16_data[1]=0x%02X\n", crc16_data[0], crc16_data[1]);
    printf("Mobus Data Sent:0x%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", buff[0], buff[1], buff[2], buff[3], buff[4], buff[5], buff[6], buff[7], buff[8], crc16_data[0], crc16_data[1]);
    write(fd, &buff[0], len+2); //with CRC16
}



void battery_charge(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                     // Refer to user manual to obtain number of bytes to send to device
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    // Starting register to read from - 6 is battery
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                            // Device ID - Get from manual
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                            // Specifies that we want to READ data (device-specific function - check manual)
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                            // Start address (1st 8 bits)
    buff_read[3] = 0x04;                            // Start address (2nd 8 bits), currently hex(20) = 14
    buff_read[4] = 0xFF;                            // How many bytes to write starting from and including "[2][3]"" (1st 8 bits) - FF to enable, 00 to disable charging
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            // How many bytes to write (2nd 8 bits), currently unused
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();
    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}



void red_light_on(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                    
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                            
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                            
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[3] = 0x02;                            
    buff_read[4] = 0xFF;                            
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}

void red_light_off(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                    
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                            
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                            
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                           
    buff_read[3] = 0x02;                            
    buff_read[4] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}

void green_light_off(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                     
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                            
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                           
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[3] = 0x01;                            
    buff_read[4] = 0x00;                           
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}

void green_light_on(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                     
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                           
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                             
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                          
    buff_read[3] = 0x01;                           
    buff_read[4] = 0xFF;                           
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}

void yellow_light_on(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                     
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                            
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                            
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[3] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[4] = 0xFF;                            
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);
}


void yellow_light_off(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];                     
    unsigned short motor_speed_address = 0x0001;    
    buff_read[0] = 0x04;                            
    buff_read[1] = 0x05;                           
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[3] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[4] = 0x00;                            
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;                            
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();
    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}

void estop_read(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];
    //unsigned short battery_address = 0x0014; // 0014
    buff_read[0] = 0x06; //Slave ID Address
    buff_read[1] = 0x02; //Function code (0x04: read registers)
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;
    buff_read[3] = 0x01;
    buff_read[4] = 0x00;
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    std_msgs::String msg;
    std::stringstream ss;

    //double led_points = frame_bytes[4];

    //ss << "Estop " << led_points;
    //printf("Estop: %f" , led_points);
    //msg.data = ss.str();
    //ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

    //estop_pub_.publish(msg);


    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    



}


void buzzer_on(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];
    //unsigned short battery_address = 0x0014; // 0014
    buff_read[0] = 0x04; //Slave ID Address
    buff_read[1] = 0x05; //Function code (0x04: read registers)
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;
    buff_read[3] = 0x03;
    buff_read[4] = 0xFF;
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();
    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}


void buzzer_off(void)
{
    unsigned char buff_read[6];
    //unsigned short battery_address = 0x0014; // 0014
    buff_read[0] = 0x04; //Slave ID Address
    buff_read[1] = 0x05; //Function code (0x04: read registers)
    buff_read[2] = 0x00;
    buff_read[3] = 0x03;
    buff_read[4] = 0x00;
    buff_read[5] = 0x00;
    write_modbus(&buff_read[0], 6);
    frame_sent = 1;
    frame_checked = 0;
    rev_frame_size=7;
    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();
    if (modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_!=0)
        sleep(modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);    
}

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg)
{
 if(msg->data==1)
 {
    green_light_on();
 } 
 else
 {
    green_light_off();
 }
}

void chatterCallred(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg)
{
 if(msg->data==1)
 {
    red_light_on();

 } 
 else
 {
    red_light_off();

 }
}

void chatterCallyellow(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg)
{
 if(msg->data==1)
 {
    yellow_light_on();
 } 
 else
 {
    yellow_light_off();
 }
}


void chatterCallbuzzer(const std_msgs::UInt16::ConstPtr& msg)
{
 if(msg->data==1)
 {
        buzzer_on();

 } 

 else
{

    buzzer_off();

}

}


void chatterCallBattery(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{

    ROS_INFO("I heard the information: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());  //Subscribe to rostopic agv_battery_level and publish it

}


/// read at least frame_size bytes, returns number of bytes read -1 if timeout
int polling_read(int frame_size)
{
    const int read_buffer_size = 256;
    unsigned char read_buffer[read_buffer_size];   /* Buffer to store the data received */

    assert(frame_size >= 0 && frame_size < read_buffer_size);


    int next_index = 0;
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int total_bytes_read = 0;
    timeval tv_copy;


    tv_copy.tv_sec = 0L;
    tv_copy.tv_usec = 250000L;  // 100 milliseconds timeout

    printf("Start Receiving...\n");
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        //always need to zero it first, then add our new descriptor
        FD_ZERO(&rset);     /* clear the set */
        FD_SET(fd, &rset);  /* add our file descriptor to the set */
        if (select(fd+1, &rset, NULL, NULL, &tv_copy) > 0)  // wait for at least 1 byte of data
        {
            bytes_read = read(fd, &read_buffer[next_index], read_buffer_size - next_index);
            if (bytes_read > 0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<bytes_read;i++)              /* Printing only the received characters*/
                {
                    printf("0x%02X ", read_buffer[i + next_index + i]);
                }
                printf("...\n");
                next_index += bytes_read;
            }
        }
        if (next_index >= rev_frame_size)
        {
            total_bytes_read = next_index;
            frame_idx = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<total_bytes_read;i++) 
            {
                frame_bytes[frame_idx]=read_buffer[i];
                frame_idx++;
            }
            printf("Receive Bytes Rxed %d\n", total_bytes_read); /* Print the number of bytes read */
            break;
        }
        if (tv_copy.tv_sec == 0 && tv_copy.tv_usec == 0)
        {
            // timeout!
             printf("Timeout!\n");
            total_bytes_read = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return total_bytes_read;
}

void modbus_response(void)
{
    if (frame_sent == 0) //frame transmit from Master, wait slave feedback message
    {
        // not sure about the intention for this check?
        return;
    }

    int bytes_read = 0;
    frame_checked = 0;
    last_ctime=ros::Time::now();

    // Receive uart data
    bytes_read = polling_read(rev_frame_size);

    current_ctime=ros::Time::now();        
    cdt=(current_ctime-last_ctime).toSec();

    if (bytes_read >= rev_frame_size) //Frame received then crc16 check
    {
        unsigned short crc_num;
        unsigned char crc_data[2];
        frame_recved=1;
        frame_idx=0;
        frame_crc16=crc_fn(&frame_bytes[0], rev_frame_size-2); //modbus CRC16
        crc_data[1]=(unsigned char)(frame_crc16 & 0xff);
        crc_data[0]=(unsigned char)((frame_crc16 >> 8) & 0xff);
        frame_crc16=((crc_data[1] << 8) &0xFF00) | (crc_data[0] & 0xFF);
        crc_num= ((frame_bytes[rev_frame_size-2] << 8) &0xFF00) | (frame_bytes[rev_frame_size-1] & 0xFF);

        printf("frame: 0x");
        for (int i=0;i<rev_frame_size;i++)
            printf("%02X ", frame_bytes[i]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("frame_crc16=%d(0x%02X%02X), crc_num=%d(0x%02X%02X)\n", frame_crc16, crc_data[1], crc_data[0], crc_num, frame_bytes[rev_frame_size-2], frame_bytes[rev_frame_size-1]);

        if (frame_crc16==crc_num)
        {
            frame_checked=1;
            printf("CRC16 Check Pass.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            frame_sent=0;
            frame_resend_cnt++;
            printf("Error: CRC16 Check Fail, Now Starting Resend (frame_resend_cnt=%d, trans_step=%d) Command to Slave!!.\n", frame_resend_cnt, trans_step);

            //printf("I am here\n");

            //Re-send command count----------------------------------
            if (modbus_cmd_resend_max_!=0) //modbus_cmd_resend_max_=0 is not appcation
            {
                if (frame_resend_cnt>=modbus_cmd_resend_max_)
                {
                    frame_resend_cnt=0;
                    printf("Error: Modbus Receive Error, Please check your connect!!\n");
                }
            }
            else
                frame_resend_cnt=0;
        }
    }
    else
    {           

        frame_sent=0;
        frame_resend_cnt++;
        printf("Warning: Receiver Time-out:%+3.3f, Now Starting Resend (frame_resend_cnt=%d, trans_step=%d)\n", cdt, frame_resend_cnt, trans_step);

        //Re-send command count----------------------------------
        if (modbus_cmd_resend_max_!=0) //modbus_cmd_resend_max_=0 is not appcation
        {
            if (frame_resend_cnt>=modbus_cmd_resend_max_)
            {
                frame_resend_cnt=0;
                printf("Error: Modbus Receive Error, Please check your connect!!\n");
            }
        }
        else
            frame_resend_cnt=0;

    }
    //------------------------------------------------------
    //std_msgs::String msg;
    //std::stringstream ss;
    if (frame_checked) //Modbus receive and CRC16 check OK!!
    {


        //if(bytes_read == 7)
            //{
               // double led_points = frame_bytes[4];

                //ss << "Estop " << led_points;
                //printf("Estop: %f \n", led_points);


               //msg.data = ss.str();
               // ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

               // estop_pub_.publish(msg);
                //chatterCallbuzzer();
           // }

        last_ctime=ros::Time::now();
        cdt=(last_ctime-current_ctime).toSec();
        printf("OK: trans_step=%d, frame_checked:ctime=%+3.3f\n",trans_step, cdt);

        frame_resend_cnt=0;
        trans_step = 0;
        //trans_step=trans_next;
        frame_sent=0;
        cdt=0;
    }

}

void uart_setting(void)
{
    //Std::String to char* (string)
    char *cstr = new char[modbus_port_.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, modbus_port_.c_str());    
    printf("Connecting to %s\n", modbus_port_.c_str());
    fd = open(cstr, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open Modbus Port - ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 1);

    delete [] cstr; //delete temp char* (string)

    struct termios options;

    speed_t baud = B9600;
    if (modbus_baud_=="115200")
        baud = B115200;
    else if (modbus_baud_=="57600")
    baud = B57600;
    else if (modbus_baud_=="38400")
    baud = B38400;
    else if (modbus_baud_=="19200")
    baud = B19200;
    else if (modbus_baud_=="9600")
    baud = B9600;

    tcgetattr(fd, &options); /* Get the original setting */
    cfsetispeed(&options, baud); /* Setting the baudrate */
    cfsetospeed(&options, baud);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL|CREAD); /* enable the receiver and set local mode */
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* setting the character size (8-bits) */
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; /* Setting Parity Checking: NONE (NO Parity) */
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;// |= CSTOPB; /* use 2 stop bits when no parity */
    options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; /* Disable Hardware flow control */
    options.c_iflag &= ~INPCK; /* Disable Input Parity Checking */
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON|IXOFF|IXANY); /* Disable software flow control */
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IGNPAR|ICRNL);
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /* output raw data */
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ISIG); /* disablestd input */
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH); /* clean the current setting */
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options); /* Enable the new setting right now */

    //Timeout Receiver Setting
    tv.tv_sec = modbus_recveie_timeout_; //unit: sec
    tv.tv_usec = 0;                      //unit: usec
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "agv_modbus_link_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    estop_pub_ = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("estop", 1);


    ros::Subscriber green_led_sub_;
    green_led_sub_ = n.subscribe<std_msgs::UInt16>("led_green", 100, chatterCallback);

    ros::Subscriber red_led_sub_;
    red_led_sub_ = n.subscribe<std_msgs::UInt16>("led_red", 100, chatterCallred);

    ros::Subscriber yellow_led_sub_;
    yellow_led_sub_ = n.subscribe<std_msgs::UInt16>("led_yellow", 100, chatterCallyellow);

    ros::Subscriber buzzer_sub_;
    buzzer_sub_ = n.subscribe<std_msgs::UInt16>("agv_buzzer", 100, chatterCallbuzzer);

    ros::Subscriber battery_sub_;
    battery_sub_ = n.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("agv_battery_level", 1, chatterCallBattery);





    n.getParam("/main_freq", main_freq_);
    n.getParam("/aiv_led/battery_lvl", battery);  //Specified battery info at 30%
    //n.getParam("/comm_link/tf_rev_delay_t", tf_rev_delay_t_);
    n.getParam("/comm_link/modbus_cmd_send_delay_t", modbus_cmd_send_delay_t_);
    n.param("/comm_link/modbus_port", modbus_port_, std::string("/dev/ttyUSB0"));
    n.param("/comm_link/modbus_baud", modbus_baud_, std::string("9600"));
    n.getParam("/comm_link/modbus_cmd_resend_max", modbus_cmd_resend_max_);
    n.getParam("/comm_link/modbus_cmd_resend_time", modbus_cmd_resend_time_);
    n.getParam("/comm_link/modbus_recveie_timeout", modbus_recveie_timeout_);
    n.param<bool>("/comm_link/tf_output_enable", tf_output_enable_, false);


    ros::Rate loop_rate(main_freq_);
    get_new_cmd = 1;
    uart_setting();
    printf("Start modbus!!\n");


    if (battery_sub_ < battery)  // Error message: no match for operator< battery_sub_ is a subscriber and battery is a double

        {
            buzzer_on();
            red_light_on();
        printf("transmitted successfully!");
        }

        else 
        {
            buzzer_off();
            red_light_off();
        printf("Failed!, please try again!");
        }


    while (ros::ok())
    {

        if (get_new_cmd == 1)
        {

         //estop_read();
        modbus_response();
        //printf("Battery information: %.2f \n", battery);
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 2;
        battery_charge();         
        }


       else if (get_new_cmd == 2)
        {
            get_new_cmd = 1;
        }

    /*

        else if (get_new_cmd == 3)
        {
            //estop_read();
            //yellow_light_off();
            modbus_response();
            //printf("Battery level: %f \n", battery_lvl_)
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 4;

        }


        else if (get_new_cmd == 4)
        {

            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 5;
        }


        else if (get_new_cmd == 5)
        {
            //estop_read();
            //battery_charge();
            //green_light_on();
            //ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 6;
        }

        else if (get_new_cmd == 6)
        {
            modbus_response();
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 7;
        }


        else if (get_new_cmd == 7)
        {
            //estop_read();
            //green_light_off();
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 8;
        }

        else if (get_new_cmd == 8)
        {
            modbus_response();
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 9;
        }

       else if (get_new_cmd == 9)
        {
            //estop_read();
            //red_light_on();
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 10;
        }

        else if (get_new_cmd == 10)
        {
            modbus_response();
            ros::Duration(0.1).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 11;
        }

       else if (get_new_cmd == 11)
        {
            //estop_read();
            //red_light_off();
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 12;
        }

       else if (get_new_cmd == 12)
        {
            ros::Duration(0.01).sleep();
            get_new_cmd = 1;
        }



        else
        {
            modbus_response();  
        }



*/   
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();

    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What type is `battery_sub_`? I guess it is not a double.

Comment: battery_sub_ is a string